# Refactoring suggestion

Tags: python

I have an assignment to refactor one function. I don't seem to know what else can I do here, maybe extract some variable into function?

```
def score(game):
    result = 0
    frame = 1
    in_first_half = True
    for i in range(len(game)):
        if game[i] == '/':
            result += 10 - last
        else:
            result += get_value(game[i])
        if frame < 10  and get_value(game[i]) == 10:
            if game[i] == '/':
                result += get_value(game[i+1])
            elif game[i] == 'X' or game[i] == 'x':
                result += get_value(game[i+1])
                if game[i+2] == '/':
                    result += 10 - get_value(game[i+1])
                else:
                    result += get_value(game[i+2])
        last = get_value(game[i])
        if not in_first_half:
            frame += 1
        if in_first_half is True:
            in_first_half = False
        else:
            in_first_half = True
        if game[i] == 'X' or game[i] == 'x':
            in_first_half = True
            frame += 1
    return result
```

Comment: If you can't think of anything more to do, then submit the assignment. Presumably you will get feedback from the marking process. But this is *your assignment*, not ours; the point is for you to demonstrate what you've learned.

Comment: Please see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 1):

Usually, questions like these (concerning working code that might need improvement) are better suited for [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tour).

But there are also a few bugs/warts:

1. Don't use `is` for equality testing, use `==`. `is` tests for object identity, and while that might work as expected for simple objects like `True`, it's not guaranteed to do so across all implementations.
2. Change the following:

```
if in_first_half is True:
    in_first_half = False
else:
    in_first_half = True
```

to

```
in_first_half = not in_first_half
```

3. Also not a bug, but ugly:

```
if game[i] == 'X' or game[i] == 'x':
```

should be

```
if game[i] in 'Xx':
```

or

```
if game[i].lower() == 'x':
```